# I cannot find the place to put the HD audio cable on the motherboard

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, case

I cannot find the place to put the HD audio cable on the motherboard. I have an ASUS P7F motherboard, and I have the [Cool Master MasterBox Lite 3.1](https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/legacy-products/cases/masterbox-lite-31/) as my case. On my motherboard, I cannot find where to plug the HD audio into.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the front panel audio connector page 46 with directions for connecting audio

[Asus Connector](https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/303718/asus-p7f-m-ws.html?page=46)

> This connector is for a chassis-mounted front panel audio I/O module
> thatsupports either HD Audio or legacy AC`97 audio standard. Connect
> one endof the front panel audio I/O module cable to this connector.
>
> We recommend that you connect a high-definition front panel audio
> module tothis connector to avail of the motherboard’s high-definition
> audio capability
>
> The card required:  Optical drive audio connector (4-pin CD)
>
> These connectors allow you to receive stereo audio input from sound
> sources such as a CD-ROM, TV tuner, or MPEG card.